# Flight, Gliding, and Falling

Tags: pathfinder-1e, flight

In working with Race Creation (Advanced Race Guide), I saw the movement trait Gliding wings. I want to know, if the race has Wings and the flight movement trait, ergo natural flight speed, do they automatically gain the benefits of Gliding wings without needing the additional trait? It makes sense to me that it should, but I am unaware if it's written anywhere yes or no, or generally assumed one way or another. On that same topic, does having flight automatically prevent fall damage, not counting failing a check or being stunned in flight or something similar. i.e. if I jump down a ledge of Xft, since I have flight, can I just slowfall down as though using a featherfall spell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rules for fly speeds are what answers this, so the interaction between Gliding Wings and a natural fly speed isn't explicit elsewhere. A natural fly speed allows you to fly wherever you like, up or down, so a creature with a natural fly speed can emulate the Gliding Wings feature. It also doesn't take fall damage unless it is unable to fly, like if it was knocked unconscious midair.

To duplicate the effect of Feather Fall with a natural fly speed, slowly descending at under half your fly speed, you must make a [DC 10 Fly check](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/fly). If you're moving only 5 feet downwards per round without any horizontal movement, your GM may require you to make the [DC 15 Fly check](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/fly) to hover.